# Jboss fuse- running route with cxf endpoint in local camel context

Tags: jbossfuse

I am working on a fuse project in Jbds. I am running a route as local camel context. It has cxf endpoint(soap), route started and started listening at /order/. If anyone has experience running camel context with cxf end point locally in the jbds, would you please let me know how to send soap message to this route which running in local camel context in jbds?

Comment: Do you want to send SOAP from one route to another? Or call the endpoint from outside? If so, give SoapUI a try

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to invoke webservice from java (client)?

you can use Service.create to create Service instances, the following code illustrates this process:

```
import java.net.URL;
import javax.xml.ws.Service;   
URL wsdlURL = new URL("http://localhost/hello?wsdl");
QName SERVICE_NAME = new QName("http://apache.org/hello_world_soap_http",  "SOAPService");
Service service = Service.create(wsdlURL, SERVICE_NAME);
Greeter client = service.getPort(Greeter.class);
```

For More info refer apache cxf documentation [1]

[1]http://cxf.apache.org/docs/how-do-i-develop-a-client.html

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the steps to test the SOAP service exposed. The steps details are mentioned in the image link.[Image for the steps to be taken.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qRlf0.jpg)

1. See all the services exposed by CXF service (SOAP).
2. See the WSDL for the services exposed by CXF (SOAP).
3. Open SOAPUI and create new SOAP project.
4. Enter the details i.e WSDL URL in project detail.
5. The project will be displayed on the left-hand side.
6. Open the request in SOAPUI.
7. Fill the request and hit the green submit button.